# security exception thrown while testing WP8 app Life cycle?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, application-lifecycle, tombstoning

I'm developing a WP 8 Application, and by testing *the application life cycle* i found that it **throw exception when i activate** the app. *( either by choosing from phone backStack or even by pressing back key)*,

By tracing i find that it enters `Application_Deactivated` event but never enter `Application_Activated` event and throw exception before it, 
this is the exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll

In `Application_Deactivated` event i store:
Serialized object in `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` and in `IsolatedStorageSettings` in case it never come back,
And in `Application_Activated` i retrieve them *if application instance not preserved*

I find that link: [is it might happened because of isoSetting storage i used !?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHSecurity%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-WindowsPhone,Version%3Dv8.0%29&rd=true)

Then,i commented code but the same problem appears, i closed vS2012, closed emulator, clean and rebuild and uninstall app multiple times, and i test another app but its life cycle works fine unlike mine.

**when i use device to test, issue disappears.**

**what is the cause? and is it affect the application?**

Comment: What are you trying to serialize and how are you doing it? Maybe you should provide some code?

Comment: I'm trying to serialize _observableCollection_ of items have (string title ..all strings and a dateatime) properties. 

and I Use
`[DataContract]
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

and

 `public MainViewModel() {
 this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
 } 

[DataMember]
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }`